# Google adds suffix to title

Tags: title, google-search

I was wondering why Google adds a suffix to my website, but I don't know why just this specific word.
The website I am talking about has a sub domain. To keep this post free of ads, let's say the domain is:

**http://sub.my-name.com/**

So when I search for my website on Google I get this:

"Lorem ipsum| Specific Page Title **- my_name**"

Original page title:

```
<title>Lorem ipsum | Specific Page Title</title>
```

Maybe Google got this word from here, but why?:

At the bottom / footer of each website I include the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="any-class"><b>my_name</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

The main website **http://my-name.com/** has the following code:

```
    <div class="title">
    <h1 class="title-text">my_name</h1>
    <p class="title-sub"><b>this is</b>a subtitle</p>
    </div>
```

and

```
<title>my_name</title>
```

Where and *why* did Google get this word from?
How can I change this suffix (if it is possible).

Thanks for your ideas, Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using entirely different title tags for your pages, Google tries to add a common string. This is done to prevent title spamming.

For example if your /index.html has the title “Foobar - Welcome to the website“, Google may add “Foobar“ to all pages with short or disconnected titles.